# Permissions problem creating a file in a mounted volume in MacOS docker desktop

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-desktop

I am trying to follow Hyperledger Bevel intro guide and trying to execute bevel from a Docker as explained in
https://blockchain-automation-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer/docker-build.html

I am having a problem related to mounting the volume. I am using Docker Desktop and I run:

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/home/bevel/ --network="host" ghcr.io/hyperledger/bevel-build:latest
```

but the kubectl command inside that docker won’t work as the command kubectl executed in the script inside the docker stops with a problem when creating config.lock file:

`["error: open /home/bevel/build/config.lock: permission denied", "error: open /home/bevel/build/config.lock: permission denied"]`

I run the docker adding “bash” to debug and I see this in the build directory:

```
-rw-------  1 root root  5692 Jul 17 10:40 config
-?????????  ? ?    ?        ?            ? config.lock
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    96 Jul 17 10:03 infra
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 13430 Jul 17 16:16 network.yaml
```

The problem seems that, as the work directory where the docker config file is mounted from the host (MacOS), the corresponding config.lock is not created with root/root ownership (as can be shown above)

Any idea on how I can make the files created by the docker in the volume map to my local user in the host? so that config.lock file is created with valid owner/group and permissions?